# Can we define pytest hooks inside the test class?

Tags: python, pytest, hook

I have a test folder with test.py and conftest.py files. I successfully implemented the pytest hook pytest_collection_modifyitems in conftest.py to skip some tests in test.py. Now I created a new folder (test2) with test.py only and I want to replicate the same skipping of the tests with the pytest_collection_modifyitems hook implemented in test.py.

Is it possible to define a pytest hook inside the test class directly? If yes, how can you do it?

I tried to define the hook inside the test class test.py using annotation @pytest.hookimpl but the method is completely ignored when executing pytest test.py.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is there a concrete reason for wanting to utilize a hook over a fixture?

Comment: I have a predefined use case to test whether, in general, it is possible to use hook inside the test class.